# Where can I find Arctic Hares in Assassin's Creed Rogue?

Tags: assassins-creed-rogue

I am playing Assassin's Creed Rogue. For a bunch of the upgrades to the equipment of the protagonist, you need to collect Arctic Hare pelts. But everywhere I go even though on the map it says Arctic Hare, there are never any there. I have been to four different sites and Article Hares are nowhere to be found.

I have read online and it seems like some people have managed to find them. So I am curious if anyone who wasn't able to eventually figured out what the problem is and corrected it.

**My Question**

What's the problem and how do I correct it?

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same problem. Couldn't find the arctic hare anywhere. I figured I'd look at the map to see where it lives and try to track it down. Turns out I found a pretty reliable way to find it.

In the North Atlantic, Havre-Saint-Pierre has arctic hares. The icon is shown on the right (east) side of the map, near the viewpoint. I've found that if I fast travel to the viewpoint and look down on the outside of the wall, there is consistently an arctic hare. It's running away and needs to be chased down, but it's always there (as far as I've seen).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe late to answer for some, but those arctic hares can be found easily hopping on the beach below the viewpoint in Burgeo. Fast travel to the viewpoint and perform the leap of faith. Use eagle vision to easily locate the arctic hares and the kill them

Answer (score 1):

You can find them at Fort Baie Rouge. Just keep fast travelling—they are close to the beach.